# Why isn't there a size method for flink MapState?

Tags: state, apache-flink

I need to count daily orders per user. The data may arrive late for quite a long time. So i think i can use a MapState[String,Long] for key is date and value is the order num according to the date to store the count.But as time goes by, the key-value will be one more per key per day and the state size could be too big someday. Since the data won't be late for longer than a day ,i just need to store two days of data. In this situation, i need to remove the earliest date when the size of MapState[String,Int] reaches 3. But i find out that there isn't a size method for fink MapState.

I know i can use iterator to achieve this and this is exactly what i did. But since the java.util.Map has size method, why isn't there a size method for flink MapState?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5917 and it explains the reason. size() has been removed since then.

Comment: It would be helpful to summarize the primary relevant information from the link so that the user has to visit the link only if they want details.

Answer (score 1):

This is because with the RocksDB state backend the underlying representation of MapState doesn't allow for an efficient implementation of a size method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really resolved my confusion. I noticed this  "Instead of size() users can use an iterator over all mappings to determine the size, when doing this they will be aware of the fact that it is a costly operation." from the [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5917) Xiaowei Tan offered. This could be stupid,but i still want to ask, is it because use iterator need to traverse all the elements or just the using of iterator even if threre are a few elements makes it costly. Thank for your help.

Comment: It would be cheaper to maintain your own separate counter in ValueState. But the cost of the iterator does rise as the number of elements rises; with less than 3 it shouldn't be terrible.